# Move Protobuf-net serializable property from subclass to base class?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a base class and subclass that are each defined to be serializable using Protobuf-net:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    // ...
}

[DataContract]
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    [DataMember(Order = 101)]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseClass)]
    .AddSubType(100, typeof(SubClass));
```

It has become necessary to move one of the subclass's properties to the base class:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    // [DataMember(Order = ?)]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    // ...
}

[DataContract]
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    // ...
}
```

After making this change, is it possible to configure the type model so that `PropertyB` in `BaseClass` is serialized at the same position as before to retain compatibility with old clients?

(The ideal solution would use the `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes and avoid duplicating the value in the serialized output --as in implementing a `new` `PropertyB` in `SubClass` that uses `base.PropertyB` to `get` and `set` its value.)

Comment: are you in a position to be able to migrate the (previously serialized) data?

Comment: out of interest did you try setting `PropertyB` to Order=101 in the new BaseClass?